# Bloclistener listening multiple times in specific screen

Tags: flutter, bloc

Hey I'm using flutter_bloc in one case I'm consuming api when user press button if the response of api return success navigate to webview,and the button inside in the appbar which means in multiple screens the problem is in myhomescreen which the first screen everything working well in the next screen it opens 2 times if I do that in the 3 screen it opens 3 webview instances can anyone help me figure out the problem? thanks in advance

well I want to resolve specific problem related to bloc listener

Comment: Show me some code,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.